# Having trouble getting one string to equal another and getting it to printf right in C

Tags: c

So as the title suggests for the life of me I cannot get one string to equal the contents of another and then print correctly. I just get gibberish for the string.  Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 4

int main(void)
{
    int opselect, mhour, mminute, rhour, rminute, exit;
    char ampm[3];
    char am[3] = "AM";
    char pm[3] = "PM";

    printf("Please enter the military time in following format HH:MM \n");
    printf("(Example 13:25)\n");

    rhour = 12;
    rminute = 30;
    mhour = 13;
    mminute = 30;
    strcpy(am, ampm);

    printf("If the military time is %d:%d than the regular time is %d:%d %s.\n\n", mhour, mminute,         rhour, rminute, ampm);

    return 0;
}
```

The program returns

If the military time is 13:30 than the regular time is 12:30 gibbersh.

Two random characters in the place of gibbersh.  For the life of me I can't see what I am doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps `strcpy(ampm, am);`?

Comment: You have the arguments to `strcpy()` backwards.

Comment: The way to remember it is that they're in the same order as an ordinary assignment: destination first, source second.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to do this:

`strcpy(ampm, am);` and not `strcpy(am, ampm);` goes from right to left. right is source, left is dest.

read as:

`copy string into first, from second`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me that ampm is not initialized so it just printing whatever is in the memory at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:
      strcpy(destination, source);

In your case source is ampm which have some garbage value. So you are getting unexpected result.

Do like this :-  strcpy(ampm,am):